# UI lag due to firebase database call

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-asynctask

i have a send button that sends words typed in a text box to a chat window. as the send button is clicked, i want to send the word typed in the textbx to firebase server. but when i do that, my textbox freezes and lags for few seconds. i understand that firebase is already asynchronous and i also tried to wrap firebase calls in asyctask but no luck. please see below snippets of code.fyi, there is no ui update after firebase calls. help please

```
 sendbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                avaliblemeg = message.getText().toString();
                // ChatMessage name=  new ChatMessage(avaliblemeg,"0");


                ChatMessage film = new ChatMessage();
                // Here we set the film name and star name attribute for a film in one loop
                film.setMessageText(avaliblemeg);
                film.setMsgDirection("0");

                // Pass the Film object to the array of Film objects
                messageview.add(film);
                message_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                message.setText("");
                long time = new Date().getTime();
                mDatabase.child("users").child(login_udid).child("Conversation_person").child(uid).setValue(new ChatModel(username,profile, uid, email,"No",avaliblemeg,"0",time));
                mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).child("Conversation_person").child(login_udid).setValue(new ChatModel(loginperson_name,login_profile,login_udid,login_email,"yes",avaliblemeg,"1",time));
                mDatabase.child("users").child(login_udid).child("Chat").child(uid).child("ChatList").push().setValue(new ChatMessage(avaliblemeg,"0"));
                mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).child("Chat").child(login_udid).child("ChatList").push().setValue(new ChatMessage(avaliblemeg,"1"));

               //new SendMessageTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            }
        });
```

//for information, please see below my async task code here that also didnt help to get away from text box and screen freeze

```
 private class SendMessageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        long time= new Date().getTime();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        DatabaseReference d1= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            d1.child("users").child(login_udid).child("Conversation_person").child(uid).setValue(new ChatModel(username,profile, uid, email,"No",avaliblemeg,"0",time));
            d1.child("users").child(uid).child("Conversation_person").child(login_udid).setValue(new ChatModel(loginperson_name,login_profile,login_udid,login_email,"yes",avaliblemeg,"1",time));
            d1.child("users").child(login_udid).child("Chat").child(uid).child("ChatList").push().setValue(new ChatMessage(avaliblemeg,"0"));
            d1.child("users").child(uid).child("Chat").child(login_udid).child("ChatList").push().setValue(new ChatMessage(avaliblemeg,"1"));

            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: @zui did you ever solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The cause isn't the Firebase request, you don't even need the AsyncTask because Firebase runs it's requests in the background thread automatically. You have to search for another cause.